# Why are some posts shown as semitransparent in the flag page?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, 10k-tools, flags

I was looking at the flag page on *Drupal Answers*, where I am moderator, and I have noticed the page shows some post in a different way.

> [image: screenshot]

The second post in the screenshot is shown as semi-transparent while the other two posts are not. Among 20 flagged post I am seeing, 4 posts are shown that way.

Notice that:

- The mouse cursor is not overing any of the posts shown in that page. If the mouse would hover over the second post in the screenshot, it would be shown normally.
- The first, and the second post have delete votes.
- All the three posts shown in the screenshot are for answers.

Why are some posts shown as semitransparent?

Comment: Score of -3 or lower?

Comment: You already looked at it once before.

Comment: Heh, I know who casted that "Low answer quality score [66]" flag ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos I propose random message for the Community user. The poor thing doesn't have any privacy! `;)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already reviewed the post.  Posts which you personally reviewed previously, but took no action on, are shown in the subdued style.